# Where are controls stored after they had been created on run time?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm newer in .NET programming.

I need to create a multiple TextBoxies at run time.

I have the following VB NET code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   Dim textbox1 As New TextBox
   static Dim shiftDown As Integer
   static Dim counter As Integer

    counter += 1
    shiftDown = shiftDown + 30
    textbox1.Name = "Textbox" + counter.ToString()
    textbox1.Size = New Size(170, 10)
    textbox1.Location = New Point(10, 32 + shiftDown)
    textbox1.Visible = True
    GroupBox1.Controls.Add(textbox1)

End Sub
```

This code example creates on Form multiple Text Boxies at run time after clicking the Button1.

My question where the created Text Boxies is stored after the Button was clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Darren wrote is correct as a theoretical matter. I am not sure if that's what you were looking for, though, so here's some more information.

Like any local variable, `textbox1` is scoped to the method it is defined in and will 'disappear' when the Sub returns. The object it refers to (the instance of `TextBox`, formerly known as `textbox1`) is still there, though, and now has a reference stored in the `Controls` collection of `GroupBox1`.

Obviously, you created that `TextBox` for a reason and will want to get at it again-- and you can. All you need to do is look in the `GroupBox1.Controls` collection. Assuming it was empty when you start, you can rely on the fact that all the child objects in there are the `TextBox` controls you created.

Now, if `GroupBox1` contains other things than your dynamically-created controls, you have other options for storing and retrieving just the dynamic textboxes. You could define and create a collection at the class level (say, on your form) and add each textbox to that collection in `Button1_Click`, for instance.

There are various approaches, but hopefully this gets you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

A `TextBox` is just a .NET class and your textbox1 object is like any other instance of the class, it is held in memory by the Common Language Runtime (CLR).  The .NET framework takes care of this for you (like any other object).  When you call:

`GroupBox1.Controls.Add(textbox1)` the framework uses that memory location (which is pointing to the textbox object) and creates a new textbox from the memory address contents.

Answer (score 1):

It is a terribly ambiguous question, there are at least 5 correct answers.  Let's start with the obvious answer:

- the TextBox object is stored where all .NET reference type objects are stored: on the garbage collected heap.

The not so obvious ones, designed to maximize confusion:

- the TextBox class derives from Control which derives from Component which derives from MarshalByRefObject.  Which permits having the object stored in a different AppDomain or process.  Your program will have a reference to a proxy in such a case.  This is unusual btw.
- your program stores the reference to the TextBox object in the GroupBox1.Controls collection, so you can think of the group box "storing" the object.  Winforms uses this reference to automatically dispose the text box when the form is closed
- but that's not the reference that counts.  You can remove the textbox from the Controls collection and it won't be disposed.  Winforms maintains an internal table that maps window handles to control objects.  This reference is what keeps, say, your main form alive even though your program doesn't store any reference to it.  And causes a nasty leak when you use Controls.Remove or Controls.Clear to remove the text box.  The control is re-hosted and "stored" on an invisible window named the "parking window"
- the TextBox class is actually a managed wrapper for a native Windows control named EDIT.  It's the grand-daddy of all Windows controls, it has been around since Windows version 1.  This is somewhat like an iceberg, 90% is under water and not visible.  Windows stores window objects in a heap that's shared by all processes that run on the same desktop.  The Handle property is a "reference" to that native object.